# Difference of input() in python2/3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is to be a simple mathematics program for my child to help with arithmetic.

However, the IF statement does not work in Python3 but does in Python2!

Please may I ask what has changed (as I can't seem to find the answer)?

```
#import from library     
import random
import sys

#display the python version
print(sys.version)

#computer selects two random numbers between 1 and 10
x = random.randint(1,10)
y = random.randint(1,10)

#print x and y values
print("For x =", x, "and y =", y)

#calculate the correct answer to the sum of the two numbers and store it in the variable named "correct"
correct = x + y

#ask the user what is the sum of the two random numbers and provide a response
answer = input("What is the sum of x plus y ? ")
if answer == correct:
    print("well done")
else:
    print("Incorrect. The correct answer is", correct)
```

Comment: the data type is different of answer and correct

Comment: Look at the linked duplicate, `input` in python3 returns a string of the written input. `input` in python2 evaluated this as python code, returning an integer if an integer is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data type of answer is string, After changing it to int it will work fine**

```
import random
import sys

#display the python version
print(sys.version)

#computer selects two random numbers between 1 and 10
x = random.randint(1,10)
y = random.randint(1,10)

#print x and y values
print("For x =", x, "and y =", y)

#calculate the correct answer to the sum of the two numbers and store it in the variable named "correct"
correct = x + y

#ask the user what is the sum of the two random numbers and provide a response
answer = input("What is the sum of x plus y ? ")
if(int(answer)==correct):
    print("well done")
else:
    print("Incorrect. The correct answer is", correct)
```